# FireBird .net provider 64bit

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, firebird

I'm trying to get a firebird web application (IIS6 64 bit) to run. However I'm getting bad image format (bit difference incompatability) issues. Has anyone got any advice to get it running.

Details AnyCPU application references the .net firebird driver (through nhibernate) which uses a native 64bit dll. There is a native 32bit dll which I use for local development and it works fine. (I havn't got the 32 version working on the 64 bit server either).

Comment: I suppose firebird 2.1 because of 64 bit and which version of DDEX ?

Comment: DDEX I've no idea, how would I find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue actually formed from how we deployed our website. The site is packaged on a 32bit computer what I didn't realize is that it also packed the 32bit native fire-bird dll's instead of the 64bit ones.

Comment: It also helps to compile on the same bitness as the target